# How to turn off restricted bash mode?

Tags: 12.04, bash

I accidentally turned on restricted bash mode. With `bash -r` command. Now I cannot `cd`. How to turn off bash restricted mode and get back to normal bash?

Answer (score 4):

Many ways:

1. Exit the current shell, the one you started with `bash -r`:

   ```
   exit
   ```
2. Just open a new terminal
3. Start a new bash session

   ```
   bash
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can type `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit from the restricted mode.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that you can either restart the terminal or do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to stop the program. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> can end all the programs you have in terminal if you don't have (precise) Name@localhost: then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to restore this or just close out the terminal.